Trying to convert UTM points to create a .kml file for a property boundary in remote Guinean protected area
I am a semi-novice with QGIS. My firm has dozens of sites to work with to help locate remote patrol stations in protected areas so I am looking for the most efficient way to create .kml files to upload into architectural software. We were given all the sites in an image file with manually entered data for UTM coordinates for all the sites. This is my methodology so far:
Used a non geo referenced plan provided like this one:

I then made a .csv file like this:

Then I add the layer as delimited text like this shown in two halves:

Then when I click ADD, then there are no features, no points to process.

What am I doing wrong?
The attribute table shows the x and y columns.

You need two additional things:

remove the DMS coordinates
know which UTM coordinates have been used. In Guinea it seems that either 'WGS 84 / UTM zone 29N' or 'WGS 84 / UTM zone 28N' might be used.

You need to change the Geometry CRSbox to one of these, by clicking on the little earth icon right next to where you currently have EPSG:4326
EPSG:32428 - WGS 72BE / UTM zone 28N locates your coordinates in the Atlantic Ocean
EPSG:32629 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 29N locates your coordinates in land, so I would assume it is this one.

